# Navigating from Shell FlyoutItem to one level down

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have following structure in Shell View

```
<FlyoutItem Route="home" Title="Home">
  <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Route="leaverequest" Title="Leave Request">
  <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LeaveRequestView}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

The items are appearing properly.
When I click on Leave Request item, the LeaveRequestView opens with a Hamburger menu in top navigation. I want the LeaveRequestView to show a back button instead.

I have tried setting Route attribute in ShellContent instead of FlyoutItem but the result is same.

Is there something to be done in the route definition above or this is a property to be set in LeaveRequestView XAML?

PS: If I navigate in code behind using Shell.Current.GoToAsync("leaverequest"), the behavior is right. I see the back button on top navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately**, it can not show the back button with follow defined XAML.

```
<FlyoutItem Route="home" Title="Home">
  <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Route="leaverequest" Title="Leave Request">
  <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LeaveRequestView}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

From above the route definition above, we can not make the `LeaveRequestView` to show a back button.

Because it's designed by Xamarin Forms Shell. If using `FlyoutItem` in XAML, it means the child view will be navigated by Humburger menu.

As your said, unless using `Shell.Current.GoToAsync("leaverequest")` to navigate, the back button will show. Meanwhile, you will see that Humburger menu not shows not.

**Note** :This should be the typical feature of [Xamarin Forms FlyoutItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#flyout-items). If not need this feature, you will not need to create a Shell application.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I used MenuItem instead of FlyoutItem to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @PrashantGupta Glad you have solved that! That will be a good solution. You can update that in answer, and if the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.